# unable to access some ports on windows server 2012

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, ports

Using `netstat -a` command i got the list of all the open ports.

But I couldn't found some of the ports i.e.`3298,3299,3600,3900,8443`.

Please tell me how to add these ports and open them on `windows server 2012`.

Firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If your firewall is disabled do you have all these ports forwarded to the machine you are checking the ports for? Is this a remote server or one you are managing on site?

If on site and you have the port forwarding configured please let me know and I can walk you through setting up the ports in server 2012.

Comment: yes we opened up specified ports through inbound rule on the server. And this is a remote virtual server on which we need to open these ports

Comment: Here is a an article for setting up ports through the firewall. Sometimes even if you have the firewall disabled putting the custom rule in the advanced firewall settings will do the trick. I had a remote server that I disabled the firewall completely, had all the ports open and still had issues. I added the rule and it worked. If this doesn't let me know.   http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/managing-the-windows-server-2012-firewall

Comment: You may want to confirm with the company you have the service through that the ports are not blocked on their end.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable guidance. I will check with the firewall settings and also need to confirm with company.

Comment: One other thought is to completely disable the firewall to test if it is a firewall issue or blocked port issue. To do so open up the services.msc and disable any windows firewall services. Then test the ports. If it works then the issue is firewall based. If it doesn't they could be blocked by the company.

Comment: Then how to open these ports from the company

Comment: Jimrice none of the ports are blocked from the company end. ISP is open for all ports and we are using Soniwall Tz 105 firewall which is configured for ports specified by SAP development team. But i am still not getting access for some of the ports because those ports are not giving internal server access.  So please help me out where the problem is?

Comment: Make sure in the inbound rules that you have domain public and private checked for all ports you are having issues with. I will available later if you are still stuck.

Comment: I had an issue once where I had all my settings in place and a program I was using still would not load. After a few hours of digging I found that there was an issue that had to be resolved in the local group policy editor. gpedit.msc . It was under Computer configuration, Administrative Templates, Network, Network Connections, Windows Firewall, then domain or standard profile. After adjusting the settings there I was able to get it working.

Comment: i m really stuck badly on this. I had tried everything. I had enabled firewall setting on windows server 2012 r2 server and created inbound and outbound rules for the specified ports. All the settings are done perfectly but still i couldn't found these specified ports by the netstat -an command on the command prompt. I am unable to access these ports internally i.e. inside my LAN connection. So, can you please help how to add these ports inside the server so that it can be listened on?

Comment: Take a look at this tool and see if it gives you any feedback that can provide further details than netstat. If it does not than it is really hard to say without taking a look at it. What OS are you running on the machine you using to connect to this remote server?